# How to find value of arctan using Maclaurin

Tags: euler-maclaurin

I need to find $\arctan(3)$ and before this, I'm asked to find the Maclaurin series for $\arctan(x)$, so I know they must be related. But $\arctan(x)$ is defined with $x \in [-1,1]$ so what can I do?

Comment: No, arctan is defined on all of $\Bbb R$. You're thinking of arcsine and arccosine.

Comment: First of all, do you know the $\arctan$ series? Do that first

Comment: I'm thinking of using maclaurin to write acrtg 3 but I can't since this series is only defined on the above.I now thought of writing arctg /x as pi/-arctx

Comment: @dylan yes I know it,is it correct if I do as I said above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly: $\arctan x$ is defined for all $x$, but the radius of convergence of its Maclaurin series is equal to $1$.

You may reduce the problem to this case, using the relation
$$\arctan x+\arctan \frac1x=\begin{cases}\dfrac\pi 2&\text{if }x>0, \\[1ex]-\dfrac\pi 2&\text{if }x<0.\end{cases}$$

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the RoC. I almost forgot the derivative has poles